Is eclipse p2 repository with includeMode slicer incomplete?
I use the eclipse repository location "https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.31/" and Java Version JDK-21.0.2. The ide is also an eclipse 4.31 version.
I have several errors with this configuration.
If i use button "Reload Target Platform" of the target definition file, then i have several errors in "Target Platform State" View. See image.

How is this possible? It seems eclipse itself has several dependencies without this, eclipse is not useable. With Eclipse 4.6 i had no one of this errors.
Here is the target definition:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<target name="de.xxx.xxx.client.target.target" sequenceNumber="430">                                               
<locations>                                                            
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">                                                                                               
        <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.31/"/>                                                                                             
        <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group" version="3.19.400.v20240229-0520"/>                                                                                                
        <unit id="org.eclipse.pde.feature.group" version="3.15.300.v20240229-0520"/>                                                                                                
        <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.ide" version="4.31.0.I20240229-0520"/>                                                                                               
        <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="4.31.0.v20240229-0520"/>                                                                                              
        <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="4.31.0.I20240229-0520"/>                                                                        
        <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.23.1100.v20240218-1855"/>                                                                       
        <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.source.feature.group" version="3.19.400.v20240229-0520"/>            
        <unit id="org.eclipse.pde.source.feature.group" version="3.15.300.v20240229-0520"/>                                                       
        <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="4.31.0.v20240229-0520"/>                                                   
    </location>                     
</locations>
</target>


The release site https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-03 works fine for me, don't know about the updates site.

Please show the source of your target definition: in the Target editor, at the bottom select the tab Source and copy the XML as text into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <).

Does replacing includeMode="slicer" with includeMode="planner" and setting includeConfigurePhase to true help (see here)? Please remove the empty lines and replace all versions with version="0.0.0" for better readability.

And of course https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.31/ is not incomplete. It contains the constraints that are missing for you. You can use the Oomph Repository Explorer to check this.

May I ask why you deleted your answer? Did the answer turn out to be wrong or is it because of the OpenAI deal or for other reasons?

Problem was: I had an other location which had includeMode="slicer". Since then i had the same errors. I thought this fix here was no more valid. But after i removed this other location the errors disappeared. It seems you cannot mix slicer and planner in one target file. Currently i want to find a solution with includeMode="slicer" for all locations

Here is described what is the difference between slicer and planner:
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html

I changed includeMode="slicer" with includeMode="planner" and setting includeConfigurePhase to true. After this the errors disappeared. If someone can use this mode this is a solution.
<target name="de.xxx.xxx.client.target.target" sequenceNumber="430">                                                        
<locations>                                                                         
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">                                                                                                                       
        <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.31/"/>                                                                                                                     
        <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group" version="3.19.400.v20240229-0520"/>                                                                                                                        
        <unit id="org.eclipse.pde.feature.group" version="3.15.300.v20240229-0520"/>                                                                                                                        
        <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.ide" version="4.31.0.I20240229-0520"/>                                                                                                                       
        <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="4.31.0.v20240229-0520"/>                                                                                                                      
        <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="4.31.0.I20240229-0520"/>                                                                                                
        <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.23.1100.v20240218-1855"/>                                                                                             
        <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.source.feature.group" version="3.19.400.v20240229-0520"/>           
        <unit id="org.eclipse.pde.source.feature.group" version="3.15.300.v20240229-0520"/>          
        <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="4.31.0.v20240229-0520"/>      
    </location>   
</locations>
</target>

In "Edit Software Site" dialog is a documentation of this setting:
Edit Software Site Dialog
